# Windows networking using only Ethernet Frames

Tags: networking, winsock, ethernet

I'm doing a project where I must write a network library for a device connected to a Windows machine.  The complication comes in that I may only communicate with the device using ethernet frames.  So there is no TCP/UDP/IP at all. I don't think the bind/listen/accept approach can be applied here, but maybe I am wrong.  Also, there is no routing or switching involved.

I have a few questions.  How do I use a socket to communicate with this device?  Does winsock have any support for just frames?  I haven't been able to find many resources on this.  Does anyone have any ideas about how I should proceed?

Is using sockets even a good idea or can I just send out the information with the appropriate headers?

Comment: I've no idea at all but it sounds really interesting in a messed up kind of way

Comment: There is no such thing as a socket at the data link layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org/), it has an an API to send and listen to raw data.
You can build your communicate layer with it.

Comment: winPCap is much slower at sending than WinDDK sample NdisProt. That should tell something

Answer (score 1):

Give the [WinAoE code](http://winaoe.org/) a look-see - it says it lets Windows talk to ATA over Ethernet devices which means it has to communicate without any of the upper layers of the network stack.

**Edited:**

As near as I can tell, if you want to send raw ethernet frames, you want [NdisSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804929.aspx) and friends.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Now it is depreciated.

Answer (score -1):

As well as winpcap and NDIS you could also look at raw sockets which are a standard part of the Windows API and don't require you to write driver code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Raw sockets allow you to send packets at the IP level, but not the ethernet level.