# WINAPI: CreateFile to Network Adapter to Read Raw Bytes

Tags: c, winapi

Is it possible to read a Network Adapter similar to a Serial Port? I know that Serial Ports can be read with CreateFile WINAPI Function. Is there a similar way to read raw bytes from a Network Adapter?

I am aware of the [WiFi/Network Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706556%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)s but the WiFi Examples are fairly sparse.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703713/windows-networking-using-only-ethernet-frames

Comment: @Kant: Sorry I do not believe this is a duplicate because 1. I do not want to communicate in Ethernet Frames. 2. I would like a WINAPI answer preferably.

Comment: Please be more precise then. What exactly are you trying to communicate over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `SOCK_RAW` flag when you create the socket using [WSASocket()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742212%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (or [socket()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740506%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), as your tastes run).  This is described in further detail under [TCP/IP Raw Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

From that page --

> Once an application creates a socket
>   of type SOCK_RAW, this socket may be
>   used to send and receive data. All
>   packets sent or received on a socket
>   of type SOCK_RAW are treated as
>   datagrams on an unconnected socket.

Of note, Microsoft crippled their raw sockets implementation after Windows XP SP2; the details are described on the MSDN page in the section `Limitations on Raw Sockets:`

> - TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.
> - UDP datagrams with an invalid source address cannot be sent over raw
>     sockets.
> - A call to the bind function with a raw socket is not allowed.

If these limitations are too restrictive, you can fall back to the previously recommended winpcap library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture raw packets you need a support driver like [WinPCAP](http://www.winpcap.org/) to do that.

Comment: Are you using wireless LAN? Ethernet should always be supported.